# I have trouble with my EditText (setOnKeyListener)

Tags: android, android-edittext

- I have used setOnkeyListener event to make TextView show text when editText is typing(at the same time). But it is not work with soft keyboard of emulator and my phone.
- Here's my setOnKeyListener event:

```js
  txt_nhap.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            txtkq.setText(txt_nhap.getText());
            return false;
        }
});
```

This work normaly with hardware keyboard.

Comment: Did `onKey()` get called on emulator?

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because onkeylistener only works with hardware keyboard, you should use textwatcher:

```
   txt_nhap.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
   @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
} 
   @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
} 
   @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
// do stuff
    txtkq.setText(s.toString());
     } 
});
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html ,  Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a hardware key event is dispatched to this view

Comment: :( request of task is using setOnKey

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html ,  Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a hardware key event is dispatched to this view.

Answer (score 0):

use addTextChangedListener

```
txt_nhap.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
        int count, int after) {
    }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
      int before, int count) {
      txtkq.setText(txt_nhap.getText().toString());
   }
});
```

Comment: we use setOnKeyListener to listening keycode action on keyboard . more detail you check here : https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/android.view.View.OnKeyListener